# How to modify an animation function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an animation function I’m trying to modify in the class of a “popup” that codes a gallery section of a website. When users load the page, a square image and background begin to expand, or grow, from a scale of zero in the center of the page to a 100 VIEWPORT HEIGHT (VH) and 100 VIEWPORT WIDTH (VW). In other words, the image “pops up” from center page and fills the screen. I don’t want the page to open this way. I want the "large-image" and background to be displayed  instantly at 100VH and 100VW without animation (i.e. growing effect). Keep in mind I still want the animation to function when the user clicks on the "close-btn" to display the rest of the images in the gallery.

```js
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.image')];

// popup

const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
const imageName = document.querySelector('.image-name');
const largeImage = document.querySelector('.large-image');
const imageIndex = document.querySelector('.index');
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('.left-arrow');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('.right-arrow');

let index = 0; // will track our current image;

images.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        updateImage(i);
        popup.classList.toggle('active');
    })
})

const updateImage = (i) => {
    let path = `img/img${i+1}.png`;
    largeImage.src = path;
    imageName.innerHTML = path;
    imageIndex.innerHTML = `0${i+1}`;
    index = i;
}

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popup.classList.toggle('active');
})

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index > 0){
        updateImage(index - 1);
    }
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index < images.length - 1){
        updateImage(index + 1);
    }
})



const setPopupImage = index => {
  
  popup.classList.toggle('active');
}
setPopupImage(0);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ff7a2d;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 1600px;
  max-height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-image {
  width: 30%;
  height: calc(50% - 20px);
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 1s;
}



.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}




.popup.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup.active .close-btn,
.popup.active .image-name,
.popup.active .index,
.popup.active .large-image,
.popup.active .arrow-btn {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.top-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: turquoise;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


.image-name {
  opacity: 0;
}


.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-btn {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 10px;
}

.right-arrow {
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
}

.arrow-btn:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.index {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

.large-image {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  object-fit: contain;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Popup</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="popup">
        

        <div class="top-bar">
            <p class="image-name">img1.png</p>
            <span class="close-btn">
                <img src="Graphics/gallery_icon.svg" width="50px" class="close">
            </span>
        </div>
    
        <button class="arrow-btn left-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
        <button class="arrow-btn right-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
    
        <img src="img/img1.png" class="large-image" alt="">
    
        <h1 class="index">01</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img1.png" alt="" class="image">
            
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img2.png" alt="" class="image">
            <div class="bk"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img3.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img4.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img5.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img6.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the line 'popup.classList.toggle('active');' located in the 'foreach' loop (*Line_13.js*). That should remove the unwanted pop-up of the .img.
The popup will still appear when the user clicks on the close button though(closeBtn), left arrow button (leftArrow), and/or right arrow button (rightArrow).

I hope this was helpful.

p.s.:
Here is an attempt I made. Try it as it should work as you intend :)

//From your .js script

```
`let index = 0; // will track the current image;

images.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Commenting out the following line will remove the popup on image 
click
    // popup.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, but unfortunately commenting out  // popup.classList.toggle('active'); did not work.

Comment: @Megan, no worries for the help. I have another Idea using JS if you wish to see it. Otherwise I will recheck what went wrong in CSS. I can also try and minimize my advice if you are not looking to get a whole answer. Cheers

Comment: Please share your idea. I do not mind if you give the whole answer. I am still new to coding and spent almost a week trying to figure it out on my own.